# SQL Server - Defining and populating a new temp table column fails only once

Tags: sql-server

How can I add a new column to a temp table dynamically in a stored procedure and populate it with some values, without resorting to dynamic SQL? I am getting an error **only** on the *first* time I run the code. It seems to be side-effecting in tempdb, and being inconsistent with [Deferred Name Resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms190686(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Consider this sample stored procedure that has been enhanced to populate a newly-added `Column2` that is only used by some callers:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestAddTempTableColumn AS BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS
    (--don't require all callers to have their table declarations updated
        SELECT 1
        FROM tempdb.sys.columns
        WHERE
            object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestTempTable')
            AND name = 'Column2'
    ) ALTER TABLE #TestTempTable ADD Column2 VARCHAR(MAX) NULL

    INSERT INTO #TestTempTable(Column1, Column2)
    VALUES ('column1 value', 'column2 value')
END
```

Then running this code *in a new query window* throws an error only in the first batch:

```
PRINT 'Test1'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestTempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TestTempTable
CREATE TABLE #TestTempTable
(
     Column1 VARCHAR(MAX) NULL
)

SELECT [Case1_1]='', * FROM #TestTempTable
EXEC TestAddTempTableColumn
SELECT [Case1_2]='', * FROM #TestTempTable

GO

PRINT 'Test2'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestTempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TestTempTable
CREATE TABLE #TestTempTable
(
     Column1 VARCHAR(MAX) NULL
    ,Column2 VARCHAR(MAX) NULL
)

GO

SELECT [Case2_1]='', * FROM #TestTempTable
EXEC TestAddTempTableColumn
SELECT [Case2_2]='', * FROM #TestTempTable

PRINT 'Test3'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestTempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TestTempTable
CREATE TABLE #TestTempTable
(
     Column1 VARCHAR(MAX) NULL
)

SELECT [Case3_1]='', * FROM #TestTempTable
EXEC TestAddTempTableColumn
SELECT [Case3_2]='', * FROM #TestTempTable
```

[image]

**Redefining the stored procedure or changing query window** are the only ways I have found to make the error recur after *ever* declaring `#TestTempTable` with `Column2`, even if `#TestTempTable` gets dropped! But then why *doesn't* it choke on the `ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN` statement when I call it with the column already existing?

---

When adding a new optional column to this output temp table, I'd much rather make one code change in the stored procedure populating it, rather than *every* single reference throughout the codebase (and there are indeed [numerous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code#Lasagna_code)). And of course, while testing I defined it with the new column before testing other code that doesn't, so it passed my testing and is now breaking on the live server.

Answer (score 4):

> When a stored procedure is executed for the first time, the query
>   processor reads the text of the stored procedure from the
>   sys.sql_modules catalog view and checks that the names of the objects
>   used by the procedure are present.

[Deferred Name Resolution and Compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms190686(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

That explains the observed behavior.  On the first call, the stored procedure body cannot be parsed and compiled because it references an object that doesn't exist: Column2.

When you create Column2 before invoking the procedure it will parse, compile and run.  Then in the third invocation the stored procedure has a cached plan, and doesn't need to be parsed again.  If you call `dbcc freeproccache` before `Case_3` it will fail too.

And so the answer to:

> How can I add a new column to a temp table dynamically in a stored procedure and populate it with some values, without resorting to dynamic SQL?

Is that you can't and shouldn't.  It's a very strange thing to even attempt.

You can normalize the the temp table and then use it in a subsequent stored procedure.  Like this:

```
CREATE or alter PROCEDURE TestAddTempTableColumn AS 
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS
    (--don't require all callers to have their table declarations updated
        SELECT 1
        FROM tempdb.sys.columns
        WHERE
            object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestTempTable')
            AND name = 'Column2'
    ) ALTER TABLE #TestTempTable ADD Column2 VARCHAR(MAX) NULL

    exec TestAddTempTableColumn_impl
end

go
CREATE or alter PROCEDURE TestAddTempTableColumn_impl AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #TestTempTable(Column1, Column2)
    VALUES ('column1 value', 'column2 value')
END
```

But it strikes me as somewhat surprising to have code that creates a temp table, calls a stored procedure to load that temp table, and have the procedure alter your temp table.

Comment: Perhaps create a new table that includes the new column, and then copy the existing table to it?

Comment: As I stated, "When adding a new optional column to this output temp table, I'd much rather make one code change in the stored procedure populating it, rather than every single reference throughout the codebase (and there are indeed numerous)." This is because T-SQL isn't an application language, as you suggest by saying "... and shouldn't. It's a very strange thing to even attempt." But I have to live with this architectural failing of the codebase nonetheless, since everybody has been historically abusing it as the application layer.

Comment: See updated answer.